# Footer spanning width of a page and centered image with previously set margins

Tags: html, css

I have a page that's under a CMS, and this CMS sets the margins. However, on this page, I need  a footer to span the width of page, ignoring those margins. This footer includes an image that must be horizontally centered.  If I know the page width, I can do something like the below for the style:

```
.bgd {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 1378px;
}
.fgd {
    text-align: center;
}
```

And something like this for the body:

```
<div class="bgd">
   <div class="fgd">
       <img src="fgd.png" />
   </div>
</div>
```

This works as long as the page width is 1378 pixels (without a scroll bar). However I need a solution that works regardless of page width. I could try javascript, but there must a pure CSS solution.

How can I change the above so it will span the width of the entire page and center the image regardless of previous margins, page width, scroll, resizing, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `right: 0` so that the element spans the entire width, in doing so, you don't need to set a hardcoded width.

```
.bgd {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.fgd {
    text-align: center;
}
```